# How to use npm modules on grunt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, gruntjs, npm

Earlier when I was using node.js without grunt I had to simply write the following code to include an external module.

```
var express  = require('express');
```

After I switched to grunt I am trying to use the following module [qr-image](https://www.npmjs.org/package/qr-image).

I am stuck with the use of this module as whenever I use the following command my code breaks.

[ This is as per an official [example](https://github.com/alexeyten/qr-image/blob/master/examples/qr-server.js). ]

```
var qr = require('../');
```

To Install this module in my *node_modules* directory I changed the **package.json** by adding the following dependency in

```
"devDependencies": {
    .
    .
    .

    "qr-image": "^2.0.0"
},
```

And then ran **npm install** command at the root directory level of my app.

Thus, Stuck with the implementation of this node.js qr-image module on grunt. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the right way to do this is:

```
var qr = require('qr-image');
```

You can find an example in the project's [readme](https://github.com/alexeyten/qr-image/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: This is not working for me as I am using Grunt. I tried writing this line of code in controller as well as the service js files. 
The error on console is:
`ReferenceError: require is not defined`